# Get exact time for date mysql

Tags: mysql

How could I make a query that returns the date of today in addition to the specific hour as '2013-05-12 08:00:00'.. I'd like to make it dynamically, so how could I make it?

Comment: 1. Why do you need MySQL for this? 2. Given that this is so easy to accomplish (with or without MySQL), what have you tried?

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 8 hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

I think that `CURDATE` and `CURTIME` may do the job. There are alternatives as well, and you can specify a particular format if you wish.

Comment: SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 8 hour

Answer (score 0):

Use can use MySQL inbuilt function **[SYSDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate)** with below query.

```
select sysdate();
```